# How to stop Slack from sending last message after starting RTM session

Tags: slack-api

I'm using Slack RTM API, after I connect to websocket URI that I received as a response from rtm.start command, I immediately receive one latest message that was sent or received by the token's owner but it happens if there was a message in some time period (e.g. I didn't receive message when I had no Slack activity on that day). How to stop Slack from sending me this message?

Comment: I just ran into this problem. The only workaround I've found so far is a 3 second delay before initiating the message event. Did you ever figure out a better work around?